# Apache wsgi 'Permission denied' error when opening read/write SQLalchemy db file, works outside of server

Tags: apache, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wsgi

I'm running a Flask app on apache with a SQLalchemy db.
The app works totally fine on the server until I try to create the database. Immediately after `db.create.all()`, it returns a long stack of errors, most importantly of these:

`[wsgi:error] [pid 23476:tid 140566826362624] [client 10.202.65.116:47884] sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file [wsgi:error] [pid 24545:tid 140566776006400] [client 10.202.65.116:45562] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/flaskapp/instance'` 
The db creates fine when run outside of the WSGI apache server directly in python on the VM. And it works fine of my local too.

All similar posts about this sort of error have suggested the problem to be either the wrong path to db or wrong file permissions. So I've checked both of these as best as I can.

```
.
└── flaskapp/
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py  
│   ├── routes.py  
├── flaskapp.py
├── flaskapp.wsgi
└── instance
└── site.db
```

My DB URI is specified as here:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
```

but I've also tried all of these variations below too (since wsgi maps to var/www/html/flaskapp and specifying just 'sqlite:///site.db' works locally) both with /// and ////

```
- site.db
- instance/site.db
- ../site.db
- ../instance/site.db
- var/www/html/flaskapp/instance/site.db
- var/www/html/flaskapp/site.db
```

Interestingly, when I include these lines in my app:

```
os.listdir('var/www/html/flaskapp/instance')
os.listdir('var/www/html/flaskapp/app')
```

it is able to list files in my app directory but gives a permission error for my instance directory, suggesting that the path isn't a problem but the permissions.

I tried checking and changing permissions of these files but nothing worked.
This is `ls -l` of app:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  345 Sep 14 12:38 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1125 Sep 14 10:12 models.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2327 Sep 14 12:28 routes.py`
```

I have tried these permissions for instance, but it hasn't fixed it:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep 14 11:51 instance
-rw-r-r-- 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep 14 11:51 instance
```

Any idea why WSGI is having permission errors to create, open, or edit this directory? Any pointers welcome, I've been stuck for 2 days and have tried every possible suggestion from other related SO posts!

*** EDIT ***

This completely sorted me out:

'''
sudo chmod -R 777 .
'''